# The Uid produce when storing info is not valid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Someone notice that my uid is not valid. What i have done wrong? Please check my database to see what is the uid it produce when user sign up in my application [User database not valid Uid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdV1C.png)

```
public void isUser(){
            rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = rootNode.getReference("User");
    
            String id = tx.getText().toString().trim();
            String txtName = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String txtStudNo = editTextStudentNo.getText().toString().trim();
            String txtEmail = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String txtPass = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    
            User user = new User(txtName, txtStudNo, txtEmail, txtPass, id);

            reference.push().setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Student_sign_in.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Student_sign_up.this, "User Failed to Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: I already wrote exactly what you need to do in my answer on your previous question. Replace `reference.push().setValue(user)` with `reference.child(userKey).setValue(user)`.